# Sometime indexedDB takes so much to store the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am facing one weird issue while working with indexedDB. Whenever I install another extension, sometimes indexedDB takes so much of time to write the data into db.
I tried to fix this issue by using indexedDB API and a library based on indexedDB but nothing seems to work.

Here is the code I am using

```js
function updateRecord({
  sessionId,
  ...record
}) {
  return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      console.log(
        '%c Inside update record ',
        'background: #222; color: #bada55'
      );
      const dbPromise = await idb.openDB('testbuddyExtension', 1, {
        upgrade(db) {
          const store = db.createObjectStore('testbuddy', {
            keyPath: 'sessionId',
          });
          store.createIndex('keyIndex', 'tabId');
        },
      });

      const existingRecord = await dbPromise.get('testbuddy', sessionId);

      const updatedPayload = {
        ...record,
        ...(existingRecord ? existingRecord : {}),
      };

      await dbPromise.put('testbuddy', { ...updatedPayload,
        sessionId
      });
      console.log(
        '%c Everything is now done! ',
        'background: #222; color: #bada55'
      );
      resolve(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('%c Error found! ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
      console.log({
        error
      });
      reject(false);
    }
  });
}
```

And [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IQwo0gLrmt5KhImohukD3lYZnjmKZOy_/view?usp=sharing) is a video that might help you understand. Also, it is not the case that it is slowing down because I am writing a whole lot of data at once. I have used the same script to write down megabytes of data at once.

Comment: It's either a bug in the browser or in your code e.g. maybe it calls updateRecord 1000000 times.

Comment: It's very random. In Windows it doesn't work if I just install a single extension, in my machine it must be 2 extensions. And the thing is if I wait for a few seconds after installing other the extension then it will work properly. And also it's not calling updateRecord multiple times otherwise it would have logged 'Inside update record' multiple times

Comment: And also this same is happening on brave browser too

Comment: Must be a browser bug then. Brave is the same as Chrome as they both are built on Chromium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved now. As you can see in the video, when I enabled another extension, my extension raised some errors. And that was because I was running some script whenever the extension is enabled. And I forgot to mention the extension id.

```js
chrome.management.onEnabled.addListener(() => {
  //This code was running whenever any extension is installed
  destroyDatabase().catch((error) => {
    console.error('Failed to delete database', error);
  });
  reExecuteScript();
});
```

And this is how it should be done.

```js
chrome.management.onEnabled.addListener((data) => {
  if (data.id === chrome.runtime.id) {
    destroyDatabase().catch((error) => {
      console.error('Failed to delete database', error);
    });
    reExecuteScript();
  }
});
```